# Existence of first order PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It seems the follow theorem is classical, but I don't know how to proof it:
For $x\in\Omega\subset R^n$, where $\Omega$ is a domain with smooth boundary, consider the system of PDEs:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}=f_i(x),\quad i=1,2,\ldots,n, f_i\in C^\infty(\Omega),\tag{1}
\end{equation}
if the compitable condition
$$
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i},\quad\forall i,j=1,2,\ldots,n,\forall x\in\Omega
$$
is satisfied, then there exists $f\in C^\infty(\Omega)$, which solves \eqref{eq:1}.

So, can anyone give a detailed proof? OR, at least, provid some exactly references?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: @user7530 I think the boundary condition only needed when we require the uniquness, at least this should be true, if the compitable condition is holds in $\bar\Omega$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $f_i$ is a function unrelated to $f$?

If we let $v$ be the one-form dual to the vector field $f_i$, you are asking, in other words, for a solution to $df = v$, where $dv = 0$. Under the additional assumption that $\Omega$ is contractible, existence of this $f$ is guaranteed since the first deRham cohomology group of the $n$-sphere is trivial. (For a counterexample for general $\Omega$, consider the vector field $(-y,x)/(x^2+y^2)$ in an annulus centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Answer (score 2):

Think in $\Bbb R^3$ for a minute.  The hypothesis

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) = f_i(x) \tag{1}$

says that the vector field

$\vec F(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x))^T \tag{2}$

is the gradient of the function $f(x)$:

$\vec F(x) = \nabla f(x); \tag{3}$

as such,

$\nabla \times \vec F = 0.  \tag{4}$

As is well-known, this situation is reversible:  for $\vec F(x)$ satisfying (4), there is a scalar function $f(x)$ such that (3) applies, at least locally.  And if one carefully examines the relations

$\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}, \; \; 1 \le i, j \le 3, \tag{5}$

one sees that (4) is exactly what they say; so that resolves the situation for $n = 3$, again, locally at least.  For $n > 3$, it is perhaps easiest to revert to the language of *differential forms*; setting

$\omega = \sum_1^n f_i dx_i, \tag{6}$

we have

$d\omega = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} (\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} - \dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}) dx_i \wedge dx_j = 0 \tag{7}$

this last equality holding by our hypothesis on the derivatives of the $f_i(x)$.  In the parlance of differential forms, $\omega$ is said to be *closed*.  It is substance of the Poincare lemma, which may be found at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms, that such forms, of no matter degree $p$ they may be,  are also *exact*, that is such $\omega = d\alpha$ for some $p-1$ form $\alpha$, provided the domain $\Omega$ is simple enough; "star-shaped" is the criterion oft' applied, though the simpler notion *convex* will do to ensure such $\alpha$ exists, *locally at least*.  In the present case, this means $\alpha$ is a function such that

$\dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_i} = f_i \tag{8}$

on appropriate $\Omega$.  The linked citing explains the conditions which must be satisfied by $\Omega$ for the Poincare lemma to bind.

The preceeding presents, in broad outline, how the existence of solutions to the given equation may be established.  Such are "funny" problems as far as PDEs go; for example it is not at all clear to me how issues such as boundary/initial data fit into the differential forms-based view of these matters; but it is certain that the domain $\Omega$ must be somewhat carefully specified if a solution is to be had.  But then again, that's cohomology for you!

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: (+1) Right, the next step is that the star-shaped result can be extended to arbitrary contractible regions by careful gluing and Mayer-Vitoris. The only thing that goes wrong in practice is the appearance of harmonic forms when the genus isn't zero.

Comment: @user7530:  yes, I know it all works for contractible regions; this is actually covered in my link.  I was trying to keep things simple, both for my readers and for myself! ;-)   In fact, the case $\Omega$ contractible is covered in the linked citing.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your interesting in this question, and make user7530's idea more clear, I also thanks JLA provided an explicit formula, and here angin as you have point out, the independence of path is infact is the closedness of the 1-form $\omega$ (plus Stokes theorem). What's more, your have prompt  an really interesting quesiton, in what manner the bondary conditions of PDEs integrate into this geometric view?

Answer (score 1):

If the domain is convex (WLOG suppose it contains the origin), it is then pretty easy to show that $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_i\int_0^x f_i\,dx^i\,,$ where we are integrating over a straight line connecting the origin to $x$, solves the equations. It's really just the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Right, you need to show the integral is *path-independent*, and this is where the "compatibility" conditions come in.  And let me say it once again:  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis if you were replying to my comment, I realized I did something silly (was doing a line integral whereas JLA specifies integrating over only one component).

Comment: Actually, I thought your comment was spot on!  Did I miss something?  In any event, one *still* needs path-independence of the integral, does one not?

Comment: @DanZimm Yes, more precisely it is path independence plus the fundamental theorem of calculus that gives it. Oh and it really is a line integral, isn't merely integrating over each component separately since the other variables aren't fixed along the line. Written differently, it is $\int_0^x \vec{f}\cdot d\vec{l}\,.$

Comment: @JLA Ah I see what you're saying, my apologies